# Trying to replace one Fragment with another in android studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am trying to create an OnClickListener that changes the fragment inside of a NavController and I keep getting nothing to happen on button press. Here is my code so far:

MainActivity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_check_in, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_new_emp
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
 }
```

CheckInFragment:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        binding.newEmpBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.commit {
                replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main, NewEmpFragment().newInstance())
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                addToBackStack(null)
            }
        })

    }
```

Currently, this code is not giving an error it just seems to not be working and I've been searching through forums for the last couple of hours. Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `beginTransaction()`. You can try this.

```
    binding.newEmpBtn.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
       val fragmentManager = parentFragmentManager
       val fragmentTransaction: FragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
       fragmentTransaction.replace(
           R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main,
           NewEmpFragment()
       )
       fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
       fragmentTransaction.commit()
    })
```